# Reading key values from hash table in Powershell

Tags: powershell

How would I go about reading all the key values in a hash table? I'm currently trying the below and it returns nothing.

```
$dict = @{}    

Import-CSV hostname.csv | ForEach-Object {
        if ($dict.Keys -contains $_.type) {
            $dict[$_.type]+=$_.hostname
        } else {
            $dict[$_.type] = @($_.hostname)
        }
    }

$dict.Keys | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host $_hostname
}
```

Comment: When you use $dict.keys, a set of Strings are returned as opposed to objects, so you can't use Write-Host $_.Hostname. Try Write-Host $dict.[$_]
is that what you're after?

Comment: $dict[$dict.keys] seems to have done the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
$dict.Keys | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host $_hostname
}
```

with:

```
$dict.Keys | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host $dict[$_]
}
```

Comment: I get the following error message - `Missing property name after reference operator.`

Comment: sorry I included a dot (.) which I have removed now. Try again.